# Force deleting a directory under Win 7

Tags: windows-7, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File I can't take ownership of](https://superuser.com/questions/79528/file-i-cant-take-ownership-of)

I want to delete a directory, but I cannot,e g.

1. Because I am not the owner ("Ownership").
2. Files are used by a process.
3. Folder is shared.
4. File names are corrupted, e.g. contain illegal characters.
5. Other reasons I cannot recall...

Is there a way to force the deletion - I perfectly accept that I am responsible for my action and I need to know what I am doing. I could resolve the root cause - but sometimes this sucks and is time consuming.

Is there any way simply to force the action?

Comment: try this post: http://superuser.com/questions/79528/file-i-cant-take-ownership-of

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate of the question, but it has the same solution. This is something else, nevertheless since the two tools Unlocker and BootDeleter also are the solution for my problem, it is OK to be linked with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/).

The software allows you to see which process(es) are locking current files and folders and allows you to 'unlock' them, allowing you to delete them afterwards. It has some other pretty neat features too, but I only use it for unlocking files.

Comment: This takes care of most cases, unless he encounters problem #1 in which he would have to take ownership of the directory. Great little tool though.