# Windows 7 access rights - Remote desktop connection vs. "real" login

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, access-control

Is there any (implicit) difference of access right depending on whether

1. I directly logon to a Win 7 system
2. or whether I do this via a remote desktop connection

as the same user.

I wonder, because I cannot delete some files, message is that I "require permission from xyz to make changes to this folder". But this exactly the user I am using for the remote desktop connection.

The Win 7 system is not part of a domain, I use "computer\xyz" for login.

Comment: Which files are you trying to delete?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/313833/force-deleting-a-directory-under-win-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Windows 7 does not have "remote" and "console" sessions as such, in laymens terms, it *only* has remote sessions, and then it attaches that remote session to your local keyboard/monitor/mouse.

Comment: There is definitely some differences. For example try changing graphics properties from an RPD session...

Comment: @Kyle - this is because of the driver that is loaded for display redirection. The actual session (that sits below the display driver) is the same.

Comment: @kyle: That has nothing to do with ACLs or the SRM, which would grant you those permissions. . .

Comment: @Farseeker: If you are speaking about "console" you are talking about the admin mode of mstsc? 'mstsc /admin'