# "Access is denied" as owner when trying to delete folder, change owner or change permissions

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

I have a folder called webdriver.

I cannot open it or delete it.

When I try to open it, it says access is denied.

[image]

When I try to delete it, it says:

[image]

When I try to change the owner, it says "Unable to display current owner" then "Access is denied":

[image]

Comment: Have you rebooted and tried again?  Have you ensured the file isn't being held open by a running process?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes I've also rebooted. Scanning my C drive now on a reboot for file errors

Comment: Also see [Unable to delete a file or take ownership on Win7x64](http://superuser.com/questions/488487/unable-to-delete-a-file-or-take-ownership-on-win7x64?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 the accepted answer didn't work earlier, but I'll try running that script

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Unlocker](https://unlocker.en.softonic.com/), lets you get rid of stubborn files that can't be deleted in the standard way.