# Delta search spy/malware removal - Cannot install/run anything

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, google-chrome

I downloaded a piece of software called Unlocker which serves to unlock files being used so you can rename or delete them. The software came with the famous delta toolbar crapware.

Even tho I explicitly selected I do not want to install Delta software the Unlocker software still installed it seconds after that Chrome stopped working IE works and I can no longer run any exe install/uninstall...

Now I tried reinstalling Chrome but I cannot start the Installer nor can I initiate Software Unistall from CP. Delta software still shows under CP Installed Programs and no way of removing it.

Only option I see left is a fresh OS reinstall. : /

Comment: One option is to boot a [live antivirus cd](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/live-cd-antivirus-scanners-windows-start/), I've had success with these back when I was in I.T.

Comment: you can try booting into safemode and then removing delta toolbar or you can try any program uninstaller solutions

Comment: Try the above suggestion.

Comment: Managed to remove delta but still cant install anything.