# How to get permissions to copy or delete files in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions, windows-8.1

When I try to copy to copy, delete or even edit a file in my non-system drive, Windows will ask for administrator permissions:

[image: Folder Access Denied]

I don't want to disable the User Account Control (UAC), rather make it work just like Windows 7. That is, require administrator rights only when handling system files in the `C:` drive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to delete files on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/60700/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-delete-files-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is no different than previous versions of Windows, and has nothing to do with UAC.

That external drive's file system was created by an OS other than *your* Windows install, so you don't have permissions to get at it.

So you don't want to "get rid of administrator permissions" but instead give your user permission to access those files/folders.

You have to take ownership and/or give yourself permissions to the folder/files on that drive., and form there you'll be able to use them without these pop-ups.

See this existing SU question, and it's answers, to figure out how to grant yourself permission:

[How do I get permissions to delete files on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/60700/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-delete-files-on-windows-7?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

There are two commands that are extremely useful in this scenario; often either one alone is sufficient, but both pretty much guarantee access:
example:
c:\dell>**takeown** /F * /R

The other approach is to use a more complicated program called "icacls". Icacls is a command line utility for managing access control lists - i.e. file access permissions. It has plethora of options that are fairly confusing.

Example:
c:\dell>**icacls** * /grant:r everyone:f /t

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off or Disable Antivirus
2. Copy file(s)
3. Turn on or Enable Antivirus

Comment: You said it all. The whole thing is about the antivirus firewall. No need to reset account.

Answer (score 0):

Just make yourself the owner of the required folder(s) and drive(s):

1. Right-click on Drive or Folder and select Properties.
2. On the Security tab click Advanced button.
3. In the top of the dialog click Change link next to the Owner.
4. Select your account and click OK, OK and OK.

Comment: how to make myself owner?

Comment: Expand this question with instructions on how to Take Ownership and I'll reverse the downvote.

Comment: Actually it's easy, see the expanded instructions above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to delete files, [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) worked for me.

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/79573/176113).