# How to open or delete a folder

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a folder on my Windows 10, which I can not open or delete.  Here is the folder properties:

[image]

Here is advanced security settings:

[image]

If I press Continue I will get:

[image]

I am local Administrator on this machine:

[image]

The computer is not attached to domain.  How can I open or remove this folder ?

Comment: What happens when you click "Change" instead of "Continue"?

Comment: The same window "You don't have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings."

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/79528/file-i-cant-take-ownership-of

Also, some people have success when rebooting into safe mode.