# How to access Windows user folder in COMODO partition backup?

Tags: windows, backup, uac

Before formatting my SSD and doing clean install of Windows 10, I backed up system partition using COMODO backup. It creates volume shadow copy. After creating backup I mounted it and verified I have access to my User folder (Documents, AppData etc). But after installing new OS and mounting the backup this folder is no longer accessible.

I have standard prompt for elevated access:

[image: No access]

After clicking continue I see:

[image]

And then in security tab when I try to click `Continue` or `Change` I have following error:

[image]

I can't access this drive with Command Prompt as it's apparently mounted only by COMODO and can't be seen by other explorers I tried.

Is there a way to change ownership or access these files?

Comment: "Is there a way to change ownership or access these files?" Click on the *change* link and claim ownership of the files.  I wouldn't do this to your only backup archive though.

Comment: But as I wrote unfortunately the Change button just gives the same error as Continue does - the error from last screenshot. So I can't do this this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File I can't take ownership of](https://superuser.com/questions/79528/file-i-cant-take-ownership-of)

Comment: The problem is the ACL is invalid for this new system, because its from another system. You are trying to take ownership as an Administrator user I presume?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I'm administrator user.

Comment: Use the `takeown` command within an elevated command prompt in that case.

Comment: @Ramhound As I wrote in my question Command Prompt doesn't see this mounted drive. Probably because it's mounted by COMODO instead of just Windows. I don't know how to bypass this.

Comment: So your saying you can't navigate to `F:\Users\`?  Any event the reason your getting this error is because its current a read-only archive.  You would have to restore the files through COMODO to a directory then take ownership of those files.

Comment: I'll try this. I hope it's possible with full partition backup. Thanks.