# Cannot delete exe-file on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm running windows 10, have admin priviledges and have an .exe-file that can't be deleted. I tried:

- lockhunter
- malwarebytes fileassassin
- del /f /q  from the command prompt (run as admin, always displays "access is denied")
- take ownership extension for the context menu
- chkdsk (does not display any problems)

properties->security->advanced shows "unable to display current owner". Moreover, I am not able to change any permissions here, although I am admin.

The program (the exe-file I can't delete) crashed before. I now have several folders with exe-files I can't delete. Any new ideas how to solve that? I'm stuck after hours of googling...

Comment: So you have attempted to taken ownership of the file, by the following the answer to this question, [File I can't take ownership of](https://superuser.com/questions/79528/file-i-cant-take-ownership-of) that suggests to use `TAKEOWN`?  Within an elevated command prompt, provide the output of the takeown command you used, and a screenshot to the command prompt itself and update your question.

Comment: Tried rebooting and trying again?

Comment: Use process explorer (``procexp``) and "find handle" to check who blocked file

Comment: Try booting using some Live Linux Distribution. Create a suitable Bootable USB/DVD Live Linux. Properly choose UEFI/MBR boot based on how your system is configured to boot. After successful boot thru Live Linux try deleting those exe files from within Linux and see if you succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to boot in safe mode:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `msconfig` -> Enter
2. Tab *Boot*, tick *Safe Mode* (see pic) [image]
3. Reboot
4. Delete the file in the *Safe boot*, then start at number 1 again and untick *Safe boot*
5. Reboot